# Google related pages not always working

Tags: python, search

So I am trying to build a generator of similar pages in Python and I am sending queries to google search engine like this:

```
related:http://www.samplewebsite.com
```

Mostly it gives good responses but apparently for some links it is not working. Like for example:

https://www.google.com/search?q=related:http://www.spacex.com - works
https://www.google.com/search?q=related:http://www.tesla.com - doesn't work

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: You have this tagged as [tag:python], but there's no Python code in your post to help you with. Indeed, there shouldn't be anyways, since your question is about Google's search functionality and not really about programming. This is off-topic for Stack Overflow; perhaps you can get the answer you're looking for at the [official help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/websearch)?

Comment: thanks, I will check there. The reason I tagged it as Python is that this question relates to my previous one, more connected to programming in Python